# How to make a quarto html document use the full screen width?

Tags: r, quarto

I am creating a quarto html document using R and publishing it to the web at rpubs.com. The document uses only the middle third of the window and leaves the left and right thirds blank. How can I tell quarto to use the full window? Here is a very simple reproducible example which, for some reason, does use the right third as well as the middle third, but still leaves the left third blank.

```
---
title: "Test"
format: html
editor: visual
---

## Quarto

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 | Col10 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 | Col10 | Col1 | Col2
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
| bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bla  | bal  | bal  | bla  | bal  | bal  | bla  | bal | bal  | bla  | bla  | bla  | bla    
| blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo | bal  | bla  | bla  | bla  | bla     
| bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli | bal  | bla  | bla  | bla  | bla
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use `page-layout: full` in your YAML header like this:

```
---
title: "Test"
editor: visual
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: full
---

## Quarto

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 | Col10 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 | Col10 | Col1 | Col2
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
| bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bal  | bla  | bal  | bal  | bla  | bal  | bal  | bla  | bal | bal  | bla  | bla  | bla  | bla    
| blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo  | blo | bal  | bla  | bla  | bla  | bla     
| bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli  | bli | bal  | bla  | bla  | bla  | bla
```

---

Here is some extra information about [Page Layout](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/page-layout.html) in Quarto.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. "page-layout: full" did not quite do it, but "page-layout: custom" (explained in the extra information source you suggested) did the trick in my example. Unfortunately though, this did not change anything in my quarto application, which uses a lot of R code to produce charts (via package ggplot) and tables (via package gt). I guess I need a better reproducible example.